# Regarding travel to Germany and France by bus

Tags: schengen

My father will come to Poland as a tourist. He got his Schengen visa from the Polish embassy. I have two main questions.

1. Can he enter from any European country if this is the first time he enters to Schengen in case he has a connection ticket to show in the first border? Please note that the Schengen is short term C type not D type national. For national I know there is no problem.
2. He got his three vaccination but unfortunately the vaccine they did seems that not acceptable in Europe (Sinofarm) I am not sure. Anyhow if we want to travel to other countries what are the conditions now? If we use Blabla bus or Flixbus does any check for that?

Comment: What route to Poland did your father state when he applied for his visa? Which ‘other countries’ specifically might he be planning to visit (Germany and France per your question title)?

Comment: Thank you. The cheapest option for entering is to use KLM to enter amsterdam and from there to poland. He will apply for visa and he will write exactly t hat time. he will have transit ticket from netherlands highly possible. So can he enter with polish short term visa from any other shcengen country? For visiting not sure but Germany and France is in preference. So, can we go by bus. I went in summer nobody checks even though I did pfizer completely. The bus not check. Flies check!

Answer (score 5):

> Can he enter from any European country if this is the first time he enters to Schengen in case he has a connection ticket to show in the first border?

The scenario you described in a comment, namely entering through another country to catch a plane to your final destination (the country that you said you were visiting and that issued your visa) is absolutely no problem. Changing plans, not having a ticket, etc. are not necessarily dealbreakers but might raise questions. Earlier questions on this site detail when that can cause problems but, if he is only transiting in Amsterdam on the way to Poland, there is no need to worry about your father's trip, that's exactly how Schengen visa are designed to work.

> He got his three vaccination but unfortunately the vaccine they did seems that not acceptable in Europe (Sinofarm) I am not sure. Anyhow if we want to travel to other countries what are the conditions now? If we use Blabla bus or Flixbus does any check for that?

I cannot report how frequently they check in practice (and we don't want to advocate breaking the rules on this site) but some form of certificate is required and the driver is supposed to check. Fortunately for your father, he may still be able to take the bus:

- France is lifting all requirements (except wearing a mask) effective next Monday.
- A vaccine is not required in Germany, you can use a recent negative test instead (the so-called “3G” rule). It also seems likely that these restrictions may be lifted on March 20. Wearing a mask is mandatory here too.

For international routes, bus operators recommend checking what the rules are for your specific route (either on their webiste, on reopen.eu, or on the national website), a test might be needed.

Rules for international air transport and entering the EU from a third country in either Amsterdam or Poland are different, you will have to check what they are as well.

Comment: Nice details. Thanks. International is not issue I know what to do for that. The issue is between schengen countries. I went from germany to netherlands on august 2021 with bus nobody checked about covid. Even though we did vaccination. Doing test is not an issue but for person who is tourist you know it might be wasting time any country we should find center for test wait and etc. Sorry what do you mean by 3G rule? For example someone has a negative test from his country before travel to poland and later on, can he use it after 6 days for example to enter germany? or best option at all?

Comment: 3G means vaccinated (*geimpft*), recovered (*genesen*), or tested (*getestet*) — same thing in Dutch. I believe the test must be recent, 24h max I think. I am not sure if that's 100% decided yet but Germany seems slated to lift that restriction on March 20, will add this to the answer.

Comment: It seems that spain and france accept even sinofarm. How can I know that?

Comment: Also, when countries accepts vaccines there is no problem for entering the hotels right? As far as I  remember, non of the hotels I visited in August 2021 wanted me a vaccine certificate. I am not sure for now! Is it flexible like before?

Comment: @AhmadTurani Rules can be complex and depend on the purpose, it's not as simple as a country accepting X. There is no shortcut, you have to look up the official websites or possibly ask specific questions here. In France for example, rules for entering the country and rules for restaurant are different. Hotels have always been exempted from many rules (you're alone in your room and it's considered an essential service for different purposes).